# How does LMDB write to the database with a read-only mmap?

Tags: database, mmap, lmdb

I am starting to learn about LMDB, but I am having trouble understanding how LMDB writes to a read-only mmap (read-only is the default configuration). Does anyone have a simple explanation as to how this works?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the [filesystem API to write](https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/blob/mdb.master/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c#L3657), preferentially [`pwritev` on Unix](https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/blob/mdb.master/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c#L3789).